# How to filter the array using the content of another array?

Tags: javascript, filter

The code looks as following:

```
inputArray = [
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file2.jpg' },
    { name: 'file3.jpg' },
    { name: 'file4.jpg' }
]

filteringArray = ['file1', 'file2']

const outputArray = inputArray.filter( ? )
```

I need to filter the inputArrat so that the outputArray should contain only objects, which filenames ('name' property) are in filteringArray.

```
outputArray = [
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file2.jpg' }
]
```

I've worked so far with simpler filtering conditions, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: inputArray.filter(el => filteringArray.includes(el.name))

Comment: `.filter(img => filteringArray.includes(img.name.split('.')[0]))`

Comment: Excuse me, I've made a small change in inputArray. Actually, there could be duplicates, but not in outputArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`.starsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to return `true` if the objects name starts with a file name present in your array like so:

```js
const inputArray = [
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file2.jpg' },
    { name: 'file3.jpg' },
    { name: 'file4.jpg' }
];

const filteringArray = ['file1', 'file2'];
const outputArray = inputArray.filter(({name}) => filteringArray.some(file => name.startsWith(file)));

console.log(outputArray);
```

If you're looking for a solution which has a better time complexity (and has no duplicates), you could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which stores prefix file names as keys and the literal objects as values. Then, you can `.map()` your `filteringArray` using this map:

```js
const inputArray = [
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file2.jpg' },
    { name: 'file3.jpg' },
    { name: 'file4.jpg' }
]

const filteringArray = ['file1', 'file2'];
const lut = new Map(inputArray.map(({name}) => [name.split('.').shift(), {name}]));
const outputArray = filteringArray.map(f => lut.get(f));

console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: Excuse me, I've made a small change in inputArray. Actually, there could be duplicates, but not in outputArray.

Comment: @tesicg does the second code snippet work for you? It produces unique elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of filter and includes!

```js
const inputArray = [
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file2.jpg' },
    { name: 'file3.jpg' },
    { name: 'file4.jpg' }
]

const filteringArray = ['file1', 'file2']

const outputArray = inputArray.filter((person) => filteringArray.includes(person.name.split(".")[0]))

console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: Excuse me, I've made a small change in inputArray. Actually, there could be duplicates, but not in outputArray.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple function to do filter operation in the array using the filter logic array items as below.

```js
var outputArray = [];
var inputArray = [
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file1.jpg' },
    { name: 'file2.jpg' },
    { name: 'file3.jpg' },
    { name: 'file4.jpg' }
];

var filteringArray = ['file1', 'file2'];

function filterItems(arr, query) {
  arr.filter(function(el) {
    query.forEach(function(item){
      if(el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(item.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
        outputArray.push(el.name);
      }
    });      
  });
}

filterItems(inputArray, filteringArray);

console.log(remove_duplicates(outputArray));

function remove_duplicates(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    var ret_arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        obj[arr[i]] = true;
    }
    for (var key in obj) {
        ret_arr.push(key);
    }
    return ret_arr;
}
```

NOTE: Updated the code, Now input array is having duplicate values. And in output array, there is no duplicate entry as I removed duplicates using a function ([Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array))

Comment: Excuse me, I've made a small change in inputArray. Actually, there could be duplicates, but not in outputArray.